# How to darken an image and mask it with text?

Tags: html, css, css-filters

This is the reference of the result i want

[image: CSS text mask for background image]

I tried putting this in css

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

p {
  color: #333;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaaMS.jpg');
  text-align: justify;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit
  ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor.
  Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas, justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
  elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada,
  posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas, justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar
  ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet
  imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id
  lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas, justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt
  accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla
  facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas, justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna
  consequat libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum
  tristique sem eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas
  egestas, justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci,
  ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula
  porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas, justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus
  a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas, justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit
  neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum
  eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida.
  Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas, justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula,</p>
```

but it doesn't seem to work

[image: this is my output]

The image I am using

[image]

Comment: Is the image called 'images.png' in your project, or TaaMS.jpg like the 'and this is the image' link you provided?

Comment: i think the result you want image has the image as background greyscaled behind the output that you already created, try setting the background onto the body aswell, but greyscaled and with an opacity

Comment: its called images.png in my project when i uploaded it here it generated it into a TaaMS.jpg

Comment: Maybe post your project in StackBlitz and link it in your question so we can see exactly what you're working with and propose a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an extra background layer with blending and make sure the text color is transparent. You can then easily control the blend mode and the transparency of the extra layer:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height:1em;
  font-size:14px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,1)),
    url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaaMS.jpg') center/cover;
  text-align: justify;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-fill-color: transaprent;
  color:transparent;
  background-blend-mode:color;
}
```

```html
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero .</p>
```

Or with filter but also keep the text transparent:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height:1em;
  font-size:14px;
  background: 
    url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaaMS.jpg') center/cover;
  text-align: justify;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-fill-color: transaprent;
  color:transparent;
  filter:grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia, nisi tincidunt accumsan vehicula, augue diam ullamcorper orci, ac hendrerit ex lorem eu ex. Morbi tempor rutrum eros, sit amet imperdiet ligula porta a. Vestibulum tristique sem
  eget ipsum vulputate dapibus. Vivamus a dui malesuada, posuere mi id, rhoncus purus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse euismod velit quis vehicula porttitor. Ut fringilla egestas erat ut gravida. Cras id lectus eget urna finibus tincidunt. Maecenas egestas,
  justo porttitor ornare tristique, velit neque pulvinar ligula, vitae feugiat risus magna consequat libero .</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your result already displayed the image, but:

1. Your `line-height` and `font-size` should be set at a low `px` amount
2. to see the image better on top of the text you should increase the `contrast` and `brightness`

This is my approach:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            background:black;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        .wrapper {
            color: black;
            background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaaMS.jpg') ;
            text-align: justify;
            filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(1.1) brightness(5);
            background-position: center ;
            background-attachment:fixed;
            background-blend-mode: overlay;
            background-clip: text;
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            -webkit-background-fill-color:rgba(255, 255,255,255);
            line-height: 12px;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A saepe sit vero sunt animi, possimus adipisci dignissimos, impedit velit error, nam labore? Soluta, ratione! Non blanditiis quaerat ratione nisi aspernatur.
        Repellendus, dolor maiores aut quae ut sed fuga aliquid cum, minima in totam reprehenderit magni debitis officia earum quaerat omnis vel delectus? Iure veniam facilis harum, necessitatibus officiis aliquid cumque.
        Amet, mollitia. Natus rerum iusto adipisci possimus tenetur. Odio hic quidem tempora, magnam quia dicta quam veniam pariatur rerum incidunt ipsum a veritatis aut autem asperiores laudantium ratione vero deserunt?
        Quos amet cum, numquam nulla nisi corrupti quae accusantium. Ipsa sit odit delectus incidunt! Quam, quo maxime. Nam vero deleniti sint eveniet ducimus, illum magni laboriosam maiores mollitia, alias necessitatibus.
        Mollitia iure impedit, blanditiis iste velit est nisi esse odio corporis. Ut mollitia illo soluta tenetur nisi provident deleniti aperiam praesentium non unde consectetur quia veritatis blanditiis dicta, suscipit placeat!
        Quia temporibus ipsa, qui porro modi enim similique, aliquam dolorem fuga unde dolorum sint totam saepe velit veritatis harum dolor commodi quibusdam sapiente adipisci nam non! Non doloremque vero magnam.
        Magnam quae, voluptatum enim tempora consequatur facilis odio quis, corrupti ab aperiam itaque autem accusantium similique assumenda voluptatem aliquam! Quod dolorem molestiae illum illo magnam fugiat temporibus qui voluptas modi.
        Assumenda quos numquam voluptas voluptatibus minus obcaecati incidunt recusandae repudiandae iusto provident adipisci enim fugiat, doloribus delectus sit iste suscipit, temporibus mollitia facere deserunt illo maiores est? Reprehenderit, consectetur vitae?
        Numquam, vitae aliquam. Placeat sequi aut aspernatur similique voluptatem ea voluptatibus quaerat earum suscipit explicabo doloribus nam animi, pariatur a perferendis et voluptatum exercitationem delectus quibusdam obcaecati temporibus fugiat. Voluptate!
        Quia voluptate alias, voluptatum consectetur dolorum assumenda quam amet voluptas, sapiente voluptatem quasi aliquam aspernatur eos dolor voluptatibus veritatis. Reprehenderit sed ipsum consectetur iusto ut consequatur autem quibusdam, accusantium et.
        Quidem, provident accusamus incidunt non sunt ut similique tempore, corrupti eos harum molestias obcaecati ipsum repellat asperiores consectetur expedita eius id maiores iure commodi a corporis! Sit laboriosam eaque facere.
        Soluta, error fugiat? Possimus non blanditiis ex fugiat voluptas dignissimos. Obcaecati atque recusandae labore delectus soluta accusamus dolorum qui, alias cumque excepturi ad animi iste consequatur fuga! Deleniti, cum sit!
        Fugiat nobis magni ipsam consectetur in, dicta, error, aliquam perspiciatis doloribus illo atque laborum! Rem harum ab voluptates quae aliquid odit, quam sunt. Soluta consequatur fugit vitae hic, ipsa est.
        Hic, est nulla recusandae ex eveniet voluptas ipsum dolor odit, excepturi ab modi consectetur culpa repellat doloremque similique. Quod ipsa ex distinctio molestias molestiae nemo autem? Fugit culpa consequuntur iusto?
        Neque quisquam dicta veritatis quod accusantium itaque repudiandae possimus consequatur blanditiis. Harum voluptas eius, facere iste quaerat nam ratione dolor fuga cum praesentium voluptatum eaque quis impedit nisi quia. Quo.
        Aperiam nisi voluptatibus necessitatibus expedita sunt natus inventore, architecto amet dolor eveniet molestias corrupti quibusdam aliquid saepe qui vitae animi ipsum maiores numquam sequi esse repellat molestiae est. Voluptates, enim.
        Explicabo vel animi, delectus quisquam doloribus ipsa enim nulla dicta pariatur ipsum asperiores eos adipisci impedit magni quis beatae! Perferendis culpa reprehenderit illum nemo cum aliquam molestias expedita id dolores.
        Totam repellat dicta, iste, quis praesentium, esse quos aliquid commodi ipsam dignissimos magnam perferendis quod doloremque. Expedita odit eveniet voluptatibus, rem, accusamus modi asperiores alias itaque sapiente quas dicta corrupti.
        Dignissimos ab voluptate expedita illo, in non voluptatibus iste facilis nihil vero architecto fugiat ut quos quisquam nam praesentium. Facilis iusto sunt fugiat. Perferendis temporibus praesentium nam autem laudantium et.
        Deleniti, obcaecati adipisci. Consectetur corrupti corporis debitis quidem iusto eos incidunt, perspiciatis ex enim molestias dolorem, illo placeat, expedita accusantium optio dignissimos maiores similique. At aliquid cum dicta aliquam vel!
        Nostrum totam aliquam rem praesentium incidunt omnis rerum velit doloremque eius perspiciatis corrupti nam qui eum ratione temporibus, ad beatae deleniti dolorum consequatur labore ducimus, reprehenderit eligendi. Ea, reprehenderit eaque.
        Accusantium similique consectetur at blanditiis maxime dicta qui ad cumque. Eaque minus rerum voluptates rem sed deleniti nostrum consequuntur impedit, earum debitis ea libero nisi aliquid autem delectus, veritatis obcaecati?
        Porro suscipit ipsa recusandae iusto in qui asperiores modi id. Maiores voluptatum nisi commodi, tenetur atque iste quam animi sit eum incidunt odit obcaecati alias velit molestiae iusto vero provident.
        Placeat molestiae similique officia, iusto hic amet eum eveniet consequuntur recusandae perferendis nesciunt explicabo minus. Deserunt ea a impedit sunt veniam rerum iure tempora sint ullam nihil? Ab, quidem iste.
        Odio, ipsam. Beatae ea quo eius, nisi nesciunt voluptatum nam numquam officiis eos iure unde dolores? Dicta ratione similique neque aspernatur! Delectus ex quasi culpa veniam aperiam accusamus maiores dignissimos.
        Officiis impedit cupiditate, ea aperiam libero repellat doloribus culpa quia eaque harum distinctio earum ducimus ullam nemo! Voluptates aspernatur deleniti voluptatem tempora, impedit repudiandae, id quis velit doloremque, deserunt perferendis!
        Non, aliquam suscipit? Molestiae iusto at blanditiis suscipit, ad dicta quos error numquam ex labore voluptatibus dolorum, facilis dolores corporis expedita sint a similique earum ea placeat magnam beatae? Iusto.
        Quo commodi veritatis recusandae corporis ullam, ab ratione natus cupiditate laborum quisquam beatae illum atque maiores perferendis assumenda. Accusantium, veniam. Labore aut corrupti recusandae modi quasi, iste blanditiis. Molestias, dolores.
        Debitis possimus quibusdam, enim iste eum explicabo neque aspernatur incidunt esse architecto, perspiciatis molestias repellendus. Reprehenderit veniam a accusantium. Cupiditate autem ab repellendus, ipsam aspernatur eaque sint nisi molestiae consectetur?
        Cum quasi, soluta reiciendis, esse ipsam natus qui fuga a quae dolores adipisci velit consequuntur dolore inventore quisquam ut incidunt, ipsum cupiditate. Modi, ipsa libero quas praesentium voluptas tenetur voluptate.
        Veritatis, quae autem eligendi voluptatibus, consectetur libero numquam minus aspernatur quis magni ipsum ad vitae incidunt temporibus magnam in optio repudiandae odio laboriosam vel? Dolore incidunt tenetur sapiente nemo. Maiores?
        Asperiores unde labore nobis. Ea non harum autem veniam, laboriosam cumque eum cum placeat. Repellendus expedita temporibus voluptas nam adipisci quasi cum ab quae maxime laboriosam. Ab rem magnam blanditiis?
        Magnam incidunt totam deleniti omnis commodi voluptatibus officia, repudiandae ipsam debitis voluptatem? Fugit consectetur tempore reiciendis vel numquam, ducimus aliquam esse. Delectus fugit vitae atque doloremque. Molestias ipsum inventore quia.
        Odit asperiores quisquam ad debitis ullam minima accusantium amet, consectetur quae, blanditiis provident cupiditate sapiente, nostrum dolorum id quas perferendis cum voluptates esse dolorem? Earum, aspernatur? Vel debitis quidem aspernatur?
        Eos aperiam labore id sed pariatur necessitatibus eum! Adipisci magni et magnam iste, repellat minima dolorem debitis nulla aliquid delectus unde asperiores, soluta est praesentium cum repudiandae. Necessitatibus, quas porro.
        Quas facilis, sapiente exercitationem temporibus beatae, odit vitae a suscipit modi ipsum distinctio ut inventore! Ullam molestiae aut incidunt aspernatur tempora eligendi rerum ea voluptatibus consequuntur debitis ab, vero nemo.
        Ullam voluptatem deserunt quis voluptates harum molestias recusandae animi voluptatibus asperiores accusantium quo aliquid magni ipsa, voluptate similique ipsum, laborum sapiente commodi odio quae quisquam architecto officia nostrum. Minus, sapiente.
        Dolorum aut unde magni et eligendi excepturi reprehenderit consequatur nam rerum atque ab, fugit voluptatum quisquam dolor quae sapiente deserunt quaerat sit sed harum exercitationem esse. Incidunt nobis cupiditate unde.
        Adipisci maxime ad, alias porro tempore quod, rem voluptate unde natus tenetur laborum fugit nesciunt commodi et. Eos sit nisi numquam ratione atque maiores, accusantium animi omnis enim, sunt provident.
        Inventore libero voluptatem reprehenderit repellendus id aliquid sequi itaque ipsa sit voluptates mollitia in tempore facere iste, repudiandae earum iusto commodi. Nemo dolorum accusantium enim ducimus natus incidunt, voluptate saepe?
        Optio a quos voluptas vero sint numquam ex quas placeat commodi voluptates id porro magni eligendi quidem, doloribus eum rem? Nostrum doloribus corporis, minima iste neque quod dolore magni illo!
        Optio error saepe doloremque, ex maiores inventore ab, aperiam eveniet iure suscipit et voluptatum nam assumenda cumque labore culpa repellendus natus, quae beatae in eaque. Voluptatum impedit commodi id illo.
        Asperiores laudantium, maxime veritatis voluptate accusamus sapiente suscipit? Odio totam, omnis eum amet quia dolor! Ab, corrupti! Vitae assumenda ipsa, officiis facilis eveniet nemo quia culpa ratione delectus sapiente qui!
        Sed aliquam soluta mollitia, tempora, ullam vero nemo porro culpa incidunt vel doloremque ducimus minima. Alias laudantium quas, excepturi facere minima repudiandae odio sed nostrum. Odit natus inventore tempora suscipit.
        Totam nesciunt sequi, aspernatur distinctio voluptatem delectus alias cum consequuntur optio natus hic deleniti, iste, asperiores nulla placeat voluptate in dolores nobis tempore possimus perferendis expedita! Esse incidunt iusto aliquam.
        Nisi provident placeat inventore explicabo quas ea cum illo enim ipsam alias ducimus eius aspernatur maiores nemo voluptate numquam recusandae, sed dolor culpa cupiditate aut. Veniam accusamus velit odit omnis!
        Optio eos cupiditate velit neque quis reiciendis, ipsam iste commodi mollitia? Ipsa consequuntur laudantium quae repudiandae officiis quis, natus culpa libero perferendis, qui fugit quia iure vel praesentium quo nobis!
        Iure optio, odio consequuntur distinctio harum omnis repudiandae facere aspernatur dolorum architecto perferendis aperiam eum magnam quasi voluptate, minima magni nobis eveniet nemo temporibus corrupti qui excepturi molestiae? Sapiente, doloremque.
        Perferendis totam dolorem necessitatibus dolore placeat sapiente saepe accusantium? In assumenda commodi voluptatum eius rerum perspiciatis excepturi omnis velit deserunt quasi architecto molestias nihil facere, tempore atque libero earum vitae!
        In, animi harum? Illo odit earum minus provident voluptas atque nostrum, repellendus ducimus sed culpa expedita libero quidem odio beatae vitae quos, nam ad quisquam aperiam? Odio itaque cupiditate nulla.
        Dolores placeat sequi, ipsum adipisci natus molestias sint, necessitatibus maxime dolorum voluptates earum similique voluptatibus dolore iste minima magnam doloribus expedita optio repellendus vitae impedit dolor! Eum ipsum soluta aliquid.
        Minima, perferendis, vitae neque praesentium ullam veritatis illum quam, earum pariatur natus suscipit omnis et itaque in excepturi architecto facilis odit quo doloribus quas laudantium accusantium asperiores! Rerum, unde fuga?
        Doloremque quia atque in repudiandae beatae sapiente, id commodi dolore est, incidunt voluptates accusantium culpa amet fuga suscipit eos nostrum minima sint accusamus ipsa! Animi dignissimos temporibus magni soluta voluptatum.
        Maiores eligendi officiis molestias laboriosam consequatur vel corrupti minima architecto explicabo? Nemo maxime temporibus deserunt consectetur molestiae, suscipit, ipsam repellat neque fuga similique autem tenetur atque? Distinctio eius perspiciatis aut.
        Blanditiis ipsa minima doloremque accusantium laborum. Maxime illum numquam, tempora nihil nam doloremque, quis exercitationem rem aspernatur rerum in dicta ab nobis nesciunt, iusto eius totam ducimus error eveniet distinctio.
        Porro quis eaque sunt cumque voluptatem maiores corporis iure excepturi quae nisi, doloribus et veritatis quidem omnis rem corrupti dolor exercitationem in autem dolores aut? Optio sint molestias quisquam dolore?
        Facilis, atque maiores. Quod eaque error unde molestias saepe et, vitae aliquid cumque laboriosam ab veritatis obcaecati architecto quam, harum veniam eius mollitia quis illum ipsam accusamus tempore deleniti? Eos!
        Voluptatem nihil vitae iure cumque magnam eius id magni ducimus quos eveniet ad molestiae saepe, facilis qui est corporis labore unde accusamus explicabo. Cupiditate minus et dolores distinctio quidem vero!
        Fugit nam ullam voluptates ipsa quo aliquam deleniti? Sint distinctio fugit repudiandae facilis nobis ipsa nam, odit nesciunt nostrum illo quos non obcaecati libero nemo minus pariatur similique quibusdam iusto!
        Iure inventore repudiandae neque assumenda dolor ad unde eius sunt, expedita veritatis eum sed necessitatibus sint odit quia voluptates dolorem vero commodi eligendi illum eveniet obcaecati deserunt rerum. Ut, voluptatibus.
        Culpa aspernatur ipsa, fugiat porro voluptatem minima. Similique, eos tempore. Officiis, rerum! Doloribus minus iure fugiat quae a sed? Officiis, fugit asperiores vero amet architecto minima explicabo earum reiciendis adipisci.
        Error vel at officiis suscipit rem quae nam quo voluptatem incidunt natus accusantium consequuntur corrupti adipisci blanditiis aperiam eum, recusandae sapiente porro quaerat distinctio eaque. Laudantium amet nisi et dicta!
        Nobis totam placeat quis, iste reprehenderit unde quisquam veritatis magnam fuga quibusdam. Ex accusantium perspiciatis perferendis quaerat neque, id ipsam qui fugit maxime magnam repudiandae voluptates expedita voluptatibus vitae incidunt?
        Hic voluptate perspiciatis debitis qui aspernatur rerum dolorem maiores repellat nesciunt? Nihil voluptatibus dolorum excepturi, aut deserunt sunt dolores voluptate, neque praesentium nam hic quae ab minus dolorem eligendi iste!
        Nihil accusamus illo omnis, repellendus officia fuga explicabo sunt autem iste nisi voluptatum quo eveniet, minima exercitationem aspernatur earum ratione enim aliquid cupiditate ab natus molestias adipisci vitae unde! Cum?
        At facere nulla consectetur repellat perferendis praesentium esse. Fugiat dolorum fuga modi deserunt, neque nulla, vel rem aut tempore ratione tempora quidem sapiente debitis molestias ab nemo delectus culpa autem?
        Atque doloremque nihil dolore culpa rem. Eligendi debitis placeat voluptate aut nihil nam doloribus? Eos rerum alias, id sapiente distinctio amet possimus aliquid. Eos, modi numquam consectetur exercitationem sequi sapiente.
        Molestias consequatur maiores distinctio. Nam, vero beatae sed incidunt, dolore labore obcaecati reprehenderit natus assumenda pariatur aliquid illo. Nostrum aliquid atque officia eius consequatur ad voluptates laboriosam vero ipsa hic!
        Cupiditate cumque repellendus voluptas, eveniet pariatur eaque corporis ducimus qui illum veniam tempore, doloremque id rerum, quam alias fuga. Recusandae ad repellendus totam possimus quasi illum sit nesciunt cum laboriosam.
        Nam similique fuga reiciendis! Doloribus laborum ex laboriosam minus magni architecto earum deleniti molestias nulla rem nisi suscipit ratione neque commodi deserunt cum consectetur totam labore, quaerat, corrupti voluptatum doloremque.
        Atque nostrum corrupti aliquam, expedita facilis accusantium omnis voluptatibus nobis eligendi libero perferendis a exercitationem odio! Dolorum nisi cumque, error voluptates molestias illum, labore blanditiis, accusantium molestiae doloribus sed odio?
        Nam voluptatum cumque, libero a quibusdam dolor dignissimos? Voluptatum eveniet porro qui autem voluptate? Labore alias quas ipsum illo voluptates eaque officiis necessitatibus ipsa distinctio adipisci asperiores, omnis quisquam facere!
        Non alias distinctio magnam unde, assumenda perspiciatis perferendis ratione veritatis amet quisquam, expedita cupiditate corporis est sequi cum reiciendis minus fugiat at placeat dolore quibusdam harum consequatur maxime! Ipsam, eligendi?
        Consequatur commodi repudiandae beatae aliquid, repellendus odit repellat, labore odio tempore, similique sit et. Repellendus, sit natus vel quo maxime illo nam dolorem incidunt magni repellat! Labore harum eos tempore!
        Nam, debitis. Vel nemo corporis eos aliquam deleniti debitis nesciunt, quibusdam inventore vero, quaerat ea blanditiis ipsum accusantium ab fugiat dolor corrupti. Quaerat quae fugit fuga. Veritatis ut dolorem temporibus.
        Vitae animi rem dignissimos minus ad quod rerum laboriosam. Quaerat accusantium voluptatem obcaecati ex praesentium iure iste! Excepturi voluptas quidem deserunt tempora debitis minus ducimus sapiente rem quas. Nemo, optio.
        Cumque officia, distinctio qui aperiam pariatur eveniet deleniti voluptas nihil illo debitis ab quaerat dolorum, adipisci, vel eum placeat veritatis. Excepturi perferendis non possimus officia reiciendis error facilis aliquam nesciunt!
        Illum ipsam nemo quae dolores asperiores recusandae, adipisci culpa necessitatibus nobis vel inventore modi, ad delectus. Corrupti, reprehenderit aliquam, illo illum esse quasi praesentium perspiciatis, aut earum placeat ipsam eaque.
        Non, commodi reiciendis inventore rem voluptatem labore voluptates libero cupiditate quae eos quibusdam nobis perspiciatis quas id eum cumque natus explicabo, iste nostrum minima nemo quidem distinctio voluptatum illum! Aperiam.
        Similique deleniti eligendi placeat repudiandae odio, blanditiis corporis qui doloribus asperiores beatae accusantium magni omnis debitis impedit rem voluptatibus, quos reprehenderit illo inventore consequatur nihil! Possimus neque pariatur vitae deserunt.
        Rem, quaerat totam unde perferendis laboriosam iste cumque non accusamus nobis suscipit a necessitatibus laborum dolorum, doloribus nemo! Eius reiciendis esse labore ea quis optio distinctio, assumenda maiores beatae dignissimos!
        Cumque esse perferendis facilis? Laborum optio ad sunt, quo numquam est? Accusamus culpa voluptatem minima non eum, amet dolore quo id unde totam veniam consequatur maxime nostrum saepe corrupti vero.
        Unde nisi fugiat totam itaque dolorem nesciunt assumenda adipisci quos quisquam velit quibusdam ut animi est dolores molestias, ea praesentium eveniet placeat? Animi eos at reprehenderit, assumenda similique incidunt explicabo.
        Fugit debitis voluptatum tempore hic totam adipisci tenetur laboriosam, assumenda cum! Pariatur debitis cupiditate aliquam necessitatibus in iure expedita mollitia alias sed eius veritatis perferendis repudiandae quidem, optio, vero magni?
        Fugiat sit dolore numquam delectus voluptatem qui eveniet natus illo deleniti, soluta laborum expedita accusantium minus cum nesciunt, sunt quidem porro incidunt tempore, quisquam ducimus alias! A harum iusto quia.
        Sed voluptas cum sequi? Fugiat perferendis quae totam quibusdam, earum nesciunt distinctio. Soluta odio minus earum est provident animi, quaerat praesentium. Blanditiis, quidem quibusdam! Hic accusamus totam rerum quasi praesentium.
        Delectus, eligendi fugit minima dicta at, quia beatae, dignissimos tempore expedita deserunt soluta autem numquam sequi sunt iusto ullam adipisci velit consectetur id quae neque quibusdam quo eum. Nostrum, dolorum.
        Enim exercitationem fuga sed id beatae vel facilis, debitis maiores ipsum sint! Cumque rerum ipsum eum tenetur ducimus magnam quo, blanditiis voluptas nesciunt atque similique ea quas sapiente nisi perferendis.
        Eum quos quae dolorem, harum quod possimus? Pariatur, doloremque non? Aperiam rerum ad molestias, natus, harum ipsum cumque sit laboriosam reprehenderit, animi maiores doloremque vel nulla culpa. Possimus, minus consequatur!
        Dolor quia possimus pariatur est suscipit excepturi harum, tempora expedita quasi, voluptates aliquam impedit eveniet nam quas ipsam ipsa amet quis ipsum. Ratione architecto nam praesentium voluptate similique eos pariatur?
        Consequuntur autem debitis exercitationem, voluptate dicta veritatis maiores esse deleniti, sequi natus blanditiis ipsam labore. Perferendis nam dignissimos, exercitationem architecto, asperiores non magnam molestias, in illo impedit sequi temporibus. Quasi.
        Modi temporibus placeat accusamus non, dolor quas blanditiis molestiae dignissimos consequuntur officia quaerat dicta eligendi soluta animi, illum tempora dolorum! Totam ducimus id ipsam! Illo qui reprehenderit distinctio fugiat modi?
        Quos, sint dolorum reprehenderit omnis suscipit quis veniam eaque et sed debitis consequatur? Dolorem sequi expedita mollitia ipsa, laudantium ratione aut repellendus hic ab non quidem ullam labore deleniti ea?
        Quod facere voluptate, consectetur voluptatem corrupti sint odio. Doloremque quis soluta repellat, dolore impedit accusamus, saepe iste numquam quia cupiditate distinctio aut nesciunt aliquid pariatur cumque quod voluptas in earum?
        Ea recusandae totam neque. Neque nostrum accusantium, quia non veniam est qui. Quam, laboriosam ratione quaerat exercitationem dolor molestias id aspernatur quia adipisci sequi et qui asperiores perferendis ipsam deserunt!
        Similique, obcaecati velit. Sapiente quos voluptates tenetur, consectetur distinctio perferendis, beatae, facilis placeat odit ducimus provident. Omnis neque sunt impedit nihil eveniet. Vitae eum illum aperiam eos, modi soluta excepturi.
        Nobis fugiat quisquam omnis consequuntur repellendus alias deserunt voluptate! Nihil voluptatem minima nesciunt numquam hic rerum ipsum officia cumque alias quo? At possimus quae consequuntur cum consectetur quidem, iusto aliquam!
        Excepturi rerum quibusdam est autem aut hic recusandae sequi, minus aspernatur mollitia qui natus totam fuga. Minima a, eos amet tempore dolore debitis modi minus numquam quaerat et, labore voluptatem?
        Temporibus pariatur sapiente, eligendi voluptatem accusamus nostrum perspiciatis sit? Doloremque fugit repellat, nostrum quod velit nihil dolore culpa labore eius voluptatem cum officia cumque architecto est non ut nemo? Magnam!
        Consequuntur libero laboriosam sint iste voluptatum, odio quidem aspernatur voluptate voluptates ducimus autem perspiciatis quis distinctio veniam cupiditate ea, ex fugit repellendus! Vitae vero perspiciatis id ullam fugiat voluptatibus assumenda!
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I changed the things mentioned before as well as the text color (to `black`)

Output:

[image: result]

You can play with the numbers of the `contrast` and `brightness` to get a better result.

I hope this helps!

Good luck!